# How often are codebases compromised?

Tags: databases, data-leakage, source-code

I'm currently trying to research which get compromised more often; databases or codebases? My guess would be that databases are the obvious answer and most of the time easier to compromise, because of an plethora possible attack vectors. I imagine codebases are harder to compromise since they are usually located on a server which should have better security in general than some flunky website that's vulnerable to SQL injection or other techniques.

However, I need to have a source for this and am having some trouble finding one. I'm not sure if this would be considered opinion-based or off-topic, but I was hoping some of you might know some studies that dig in to this. I would also be happy with some numbers from an article, or a better way of searching for the information.

Specifically I'm looking for cases where the attacker is able to view the code used for the program (for example by gaining access to the developers machine, or breaching a server and having a look at the files).

Comment: A good source for such info is the [Data Breach Investigations Report](http://www.verizonenterprise.com/DBIR/)

Comment: To give another completely baseless and intuitive argument: Codebases can be leaked easier because there are plenty of copies on the personal machines of the developers while the production database is usually far better protected.

Comment: What exactly you consider a compromise of a code base? Insertion of a backdoor by an attacker into the source code, detection of an existing backdoor, detection of security issue which can be used as backdoor, insertion of code into a specific instance of the code like with DLL injection ... ?

Comment: This isn't off-topic but I can't find of any good methodology to answer your question. The DBIR cited above would be the closest to an objective global assessment that is available. Never seen papers on how many e.g. Github repos contain malware or on how many servers run purposedly broken code.

Comment: @Philipp exactly the reason I'm trying to figure out if what I'm thinking is actually true ;) I can think anything I want, but that doesn't mean it's true.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I guess I should have specified that more clearly. Specifically I'm looking for cases where the attacker is able to view the code used for the program (for example by gaining access to the developers machine, or breaching a server and having a look at the files).

Comment: You don't need access to the dev's gig if you can reverse-engineer the program. Leaving traces and all that...

Comment: @Bono: so you want to compare access to source code vs. access to database instance. I think this would be a bad kind of comparison since there are way more database instances then relevant source code but on the other hand compromise of a single code base can lead to lots of compromises. So it would be better to compare compromises **caused by** access to the source code with the compromises of database instances. Thus you would also get all the compromises of browsers caused by the open access to the source code of firefox and chrome.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Damn, guess I'm still not specific enough. My main interest would be for keys and passwords stored in files in comparison to a database. For example; would it be safer to store a key for a service (let's say... an SMS sending service as example) in the codebase or in a database? This would be mainly server side languages I'm talking about, so no JS or HTML worries. My idea is that, since (I think) codebases are less often compromised (viewed) it would be safer to store them there, than in a database of sorts.

Comment: @Bono: so you are actually not interested in what gets more compromised, but what is harder to compromise and where the secret is safer. The actual numbers don't matter because if everybody will store the keys in the code you will see more attacks at the code. Apart from that you don't necessarily need access to the source code to extract the secret, but it can often be extracted from the compiled program or from the memory of a running instance.

Comment: @Bono Service keys belong into neither. [Any secret credentials should be a part of the configuration](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/205606/strategy-for-keeping-secret-info-such-as-api-keys-out-of-source-control). Which leads us to a third attack target: configuration files on the production machine.

Comment: While this is an interesting topic the discussion here suggests that the current question is too broad. Therefore I recommend to close it and to create a new question (unless it exists already) about how to store the necessary secrets in the best way.